# JDOM getChilden not showing all children

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jdom

My xml looks like this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Objects>
    <object1>object1Value</object1>
    <object2>object1Value</object2>
  </Objects>
</root>
```

To show all objects under "Objects" I am using code-

```
    List collected_objects = rootNode.getChildren("Objects");

    ListIterator litr = collected_objects.listIterator();
    while (litr.hasNext()) {

        Element  element = (Element) litr.next();
        System.out.println(element.toString());
    }
```

but it displays-

```
[Element: <Objects/>]
```

Why isn't it showing two objects?

Comment: What is rootNode? Just a Node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call a `NodeList objectList = element.getChildNodes()` on each of the `collected_objects` and iterate through the returned list, since in your XML `<object1>, <object2>...` nodes are children of the `<Objects>.`